# Angular 2 Component - "No definition found for ..."

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm working with angular 2 in VSCode. I'm just learning my way around this IDE. I'm trying to figure out how to use CTRL+Click to navigate to component properties like `templatUrl` but it's not working for me (See screenshot).

I would expect that when I CTRL+Click the text it opens the file `dashboard.component.html` Is there an extension I need to install to get this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the ctrl + click only works on entities that the language service (Typescript language service) can expose to the IDE.

For example, you can ctrl + click to navigate to DashboardComponent from app module where you import them. The templateUrl property is a string and ctrl + click does not work there.

Alternate option (that I use) is to press ctrl + P that brings up the 'Go To File' popup and  you can start typing 'dashboard html' - it actually uses a regex pattern search (dashoboard.component.html, dashboarddetails.component.html etc) to find matches and display them in a dropdown from which you can use the up or down arrow keys and hit enter to navigate to that file.